# ERROR: column does not exist on PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I'm creating an API with Spring Boot (3.1.1), Java, PostgreSQL and Flyway. I started by doing the security settings with Spring Security, creating a user that could have 3 roles (ADMIN, USER, CUSTOMER). The user authentication, authorization and get all/update/delete functions worked without problems.
However, I wanted Customer to have more attributes than I put in User, so I created a class called Customer and inherited it from User. I've done this in the code and in the migration. I can register users normally, but when I try to login with a User that I saved in the database, I get the error:

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
ERROR: column u1_0.accounttype does not exist
Posição: 62
```

However, I didn't put this *accounttype* attribute in the User class, only in the Customer class.

**Class User**

```
package com.example.auth.domain.user;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Table(name = "users")
@Entity(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private UserRole role;

    public User(String login, String password, UserRole role){
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        if(this.role == UserRole.ADMIN){
            return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_CUSTOMER"));
        } 
        else if(this.role == UserRole.USER){
            return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_CUSTOMER"));
        }
        else{
            return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_CUSTOMER"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Class Customer:**

```
package com.example.auth.domain.costumer;

import com.example.auth.domain.user.User;
import com.example.auth.domain.user.UserRole;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity(name = "customers")
@Table(name="customers")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer extends User{

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private Integer relationshipTime;
    private Integer age;
    private CustomerContactRole contactorigin;
    private CustomerAccountTypeRole accounttype;

    public Customer(String login, String password, String name, String email, String phone,
            Integer relationshipTime, Integer age, CustomerContactRole contactOrigin,
            CustomerAccountTypeRole accountType) {
        super(login, password, UserRole.CUSTOMER);
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.relationshipTime = relationshipTime;
        this.age = age;
        this.contactorigin = contactOrigin;
        this.accounttype = accountType;
    }

}
```

**Migration: V1__create-product-user-customer-table.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    price INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE users (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    login TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    role TEXT NOT NULL,
    dtype TEXT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE customers (
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    phone TEXT NOT NULL,
    relationshiptime INTEGER NOT NULL,
    age INTEGER NOT NULL,
    contactorigin TEXT NOT NULL,
    accounttype TEXT NOT NULL
) inherits (users);
```

**Endpoint that generates the error (when I try to login an User)**

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody @Valid AuthenticationDTO data){
        var usernamePassword = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(data.login(), data.password());
//Line that causes the error
        var auth = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePassword);

        String token = tokenService.generateToken((User) auth.getPrincipal());

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Login finished! " + new LoginResponseDTO(token));
    }
```

**Error**

```
2023-07-27T13:02:17.441-03:00  WARN 8700 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
2023-07-27T13:02:17.441-03:00 ERROR 8700 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column u1_0.accounttype does not exist
  Posição: 62
```

Comment: have you tried to specify schema in table annotation?
@Table(name="table_name", schema = "myapp")

Comment: [Edit] your post and include the _complete_ stack trace; indicate the line in your code that causes the exception.

Comment: @BlackBear In which table, in the Users table?

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for your advice. I will indicate the line that causes the exception.